# LDAP in PHP code "Can't contact LDAP server" in windows server

Tags: php, windows, ssl, ldap

I have a problem in connecting to LDAP from windows server using PHP. My codes are below:

```
<?php

$ldaprdn  = 'myusername';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'mypassword';

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("LDAP://myDomain")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
if ($ldapconn) {        
var_dump(ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass));

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind  successful...";
    } else {
        echo ldap_error($ldapconn);
        echo "LDAP bind  failed...";
    }

}

?>
```

I always get "Can't contact LDAP server" error message. If I used .net application using same username, password, and domain, the connection always be made successfully. Am I doing wrong in the codes or perhaps configuration should be made?

Comment: You should certainly set the options before doing the connect. When you get an error, print it. Don't just print some message of our own devising. Otherwise debugging just becomes a guessing game.

Comment: can you contact the ldap server from the machine running php? does a known good tool sich als ldapsearch does return the results you want?

Comment: I have found the answers.. I changed the domain name into IP address and connection can be made.